# How do I perform a nested join in sails.js and waterline?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) I have the following models:

**Site**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultTo: false
    },
    pages: {
        collection: 'page',
        via 'site'
    }
  }
};
```

**Page**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    site: {
        model: 'site',
        required: true
    },
    modules: {
        collection: 'module',
        via 'page'
    }
  }
};
```

**Module**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    module: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    page: {
        model: 'page',
        required: true
    }
  }
};
```

When I call *GET /Site/1* I get the following:

```
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "name": "First page",
            "site": 1,
            "createdAt": "2014-08-23T17:57:41.562Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-08-23T17:57:41.562Z",
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "name": "First site",
    "createdAt": "2014-08-23T17:56:57.143Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-08-23T17:56:57.143Z",
    "id": 1
}
```

I'm using MongoDB and this would be dead easy to model as a nested document.. unfortunately I don't think Waterline supports that, hence the assocations/joins.

I can see that it's successfully outputting each page associated with a site, how do I make it so it also outputs the list of modules that are associated with each page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sails.js populate nested associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations) might help. Essentially, there is no direct way to grab nested associations yet.