# Sails/Waterline Populate doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm bangin' my head against the wall in the last hours, and I can't figure out a solution to my problem. In my sails models, I have 2 one-to-many associations. 'A' model can have many 'B', and 'B' model can have many 'C'. In my controller, when I do `a.find().populate('b') (...)` it returns me the entire collection of A model, but populate each entry of A model with only one B, which doesn't match the current dataset I have in my database(mysql). And doesn't populate the C entries in the B model. In other words, I'm trying to achieve something like *nested population.*
It's something wrong with the Controller code, right? How can I make this work?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Company.js

```
module.exports = {

identity: 'company',

attributes: {

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    address: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    zip_code: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    city: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    nif: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        minLength: 9
    },

    country: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    phone_number: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true
    },

    facilities: {
        collection: 'facility',
        references: 'facility',
        on: 'id',
        via: 'company'
    }
  }
};
```

Facility.js

```
module.exports = {

identity: 'facility',

attributes: {

    company: {
        columnName: 'id_company',
        model: 'company'
    },

    warehouses: {
        collection: 'warehouse',
        references: 'warehouse',
        on: 'id',
        via: 'facility'
    },

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    address: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    zip_code: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    city: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    country: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    phone_number: {
        type: 'string',
    },

    email: {
        type: 'email',
    },

    longitude: {
        type: 'float',
    },

    latitude: {
        type: 'float'
    }

  }
};
```

Warehouse.js

```
module.exports = {

identity: 'warehouse',

attributes: {

    facility: {
        columnName: 'id_facility',
        model: 'facility',
    },

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    longitude: {
        type: 'float',
    },

    latitude: {
        type: 'float'
    }

  }
};
```

MainController's relevant code:

```
companies: function(req, res) {
    company.find().populate('facilities').exec(function(err, comp){
        var error = '';
        if(err){
            error = 'Unable to retrieve the requested information. Try again later and, if the problem persists, contact the platform administrator.';
        } else if(!comp[0]) {
            error = 'There\'s no company data inserted.';
        }
        // (...)
    });

},
```

Comment: Could you share your models and controller code?

Comment: @RobertIgnat thank you for replying. I've added some relevant code to the question.

Comment: First of all, Waterline does not support nested population at the moment, so `Company.find().populate('facilities')` will only populate the facilities for each company, but not the warehouses for each facility.
Second of all, have you tried removing `references` and `on` in your models? If yes and you get the same behavior, can you show an example of the response?

Comment: @RobertIgnat thank you again. I'll try that and show my results afterwards.

Comment: @RobertIgnat please post that as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. It worked, you're the Man!! thanks :)

Comment: @RobertIgnat by the way, do you know how can I populate my response with the warehouses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `references` and `on` from your models.

Regarding nested population, just like I said in the comment, Waterline does not currently support it. You could check [Waterline2](https://github.com/mikermcneil/waterline2) which, as they say, offers the possibility of nested populating, but is not recommended for production.
Otherwise you could check this out: [Sails.js populate nested associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations)

Comment: In this moment, I cannot switch to waterline2 because my app have an significant amount of code, and will switch to production soon. But I'll check the new Waterline! Thank you! :)