# Sails.js req.options.where with associations deeper then one level

Tags: authorization, sails.js

Is it possible to use `req.options.where` with associations that are more then one level?

If so how?

If not, what is the 'correct way' to go about creating a policy for the following scenario.

I have 3 models
User
Parent
Child

I have the vanilla blueprint actions for all the models.

Children have parents and parents have users.

In my policy I would like to add to the request; the instructions to only return Children of a particular user.

Hopefully it will be similar to the following:

For a Parent request

```
req.options.where.user = req.session.current_user_id
```

I am not using 'populate where' functionality of blueprint for this scenario.

Presently, when some one hits the child find action, it displays all the children.  I am trying to just allow them to see children of the logged in user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No it's not possible at the moment. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations?rq=1 for more informations about populating nested associations

Comment: @YannBertrand, thanks!  This is pretty disappointing though.  I took a look at the link, and while informative, I am not sure how this helps me with the policy or sending along the req.option in my policy.