# Populating multiple tables in sails waterline orm

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I am working on a sails applications which contains multiple(>2) tables which I need to join with the help of **populate method**
e.g.

**Category.js model**

```
attributes: {
    CategoryID:{
        type:"integer",
        required:true,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true
    },
    SubCategories:{                  //REFERING TO SUB-CATEGORY TABLE
        collection:'SubCategory',
        via:'CategoryID'
    },
    CategoryName:{
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        maxLength:50
    }
  }
```

this is **SubCategory.js model**.

```
attributes: {
    id:{
        type:'integer',
        required:true,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true,
        maxLength:10,
        columnName:'SubCategoryID'
    },
    CategoryID:{
        model:'Category'                 //REFERING TO CATEGORY TABLE
    },
    ProductsOfCategory:{                  //REFERING TO PRODUCT TABLE
        collection:'Product',
        via:'SubCategoryID'
    },
    SubCategory:{
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        maxLength:50
    }
}
```

and **Product.js model**

```
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        maxLength: 10,
        columnName:'ProductID'
    },
    SubCategoryID: {
        model:'SubCategory'
    },
    ProductDetails:{
        collection:'ProductDetails',
        via:'ProductID'
    },
    ProductName: {
        type: "string",
        required: true,
        maxLength: 50
    }
}
```

and **ProductDeatils.js model**

```
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        maxLength: 10,
        columnName:'ProductDetailID'
    },
    ProductID:{
        model:'Product'
    },
    Size:{
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        maxLength:10
    },
    Color:{
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        maxLength:10
    }
}
```

On Populating, I am able to populate the category and sub-category of each category.

```
Category.find()
        .populate('SubCategories')
        .exec(function(err, categories){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.json(err);
            }
            console.log(categories);
            res.json(categories);
        })
```

**How to populate the all above table in one go such that after final query we get all the above details in one json.**

**We get join of all above tables**

**that is category having all sub-categories, sub-category having all products and all product have product details in one json**

Comment: ashishkumar - did my answer assist you? Please can you mark as correct answer if you found it helpful. Have also linked to a (slightly dated but very similar) SOF question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask a great question. There has been **massive** interest in getting nested populate feature into sails, literally tens of issue requests and PRs etc.

Take a look at some history here:

[[FEATURE REQUEST] Recursively populate #308](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308)  - i was late to the party, making the request on October 29th 2014 as you'll see in the history.

As far as I know, most conversations eventually converged here (after a couple of years of Sails users requesting the feature):

[Deep populate #1052](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/1052) (the issue remains **open** as of writing **14 Jan 2016**)

It is unclear from the state of that Issue where we are. The history of both links does suggest alternative workarounds others have used.

My **hunch** is that recursive populate is not supported out of the box.

What I did when using waterline model associations with SailsJS, was work with a package like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) - use something like waterfall to explicitly populate the child relationships programmatically. You can combine doing this with overriding the default [toJSON()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) of the models you invoke to add their relationships (which you have programmatically populated) to the JSON response. You could equally choose to use the built-in promises to achieve the same thing.

Found this (dated, 2014) [SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446484/sails-js-populate-nested-associations) which offers more information.

Someone, do please correct me here if I have missed this feature addition in a recent Sails or Waterline version - couldn't find anything in the release notes for either project to say this was supported.